# Computational budget vs. computing budget vs. computation budget

Tags: difference

I want to talk about how much CPU/GPU time an activity requires. Shall I call it "*computational* budget", "*computing* budget", or "*computation* budget"?

Both terms have around 20k results on Google.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_computing_budget_allocation talks about both computational budget and computing budget in a seemingly interchangeable way.

Comment: *[H]ow much CPU/GPU time an activity requires* makes me think it's more like it's "computation cost".

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thanks, good point. I guess We could extend the question to: Computational budget vs. computing budget vs. computation budget :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Computational budget vs. computing budget vs. computation budget

Let's look at the dictionary definitions:

> Computational
>   Of, relating to, or using computers.

> Computing
>   the use or operation of computers.

> Computation
>   the use of computers, especially as a subject of research or study.

So *computing* is a narrower field than *computational*, and is pretty much the same as *computation*.

You are talking about the time required to run on a computer, so I would say that *Computing* fits best.

> The computing budget is 11 hours

*budget* doesn't really fit here.

> allow or provide a particular amount of money

it is specifically referring to money, and you want time. Maybe allowance works better:

> the amount of something that is permitted

but I would simply say:

> The computing time required is 11 hours.